# How to use MVC design pattern in a spring console application

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, design-patterns, console-application

I developed an application which gets the data from the user from the console and pass the data to the frontend and Spring rest api is used for that purpose. So now I want to rearrange the folder structure according to the MVC.
Can you please check what I've done so far and correct me if I'm wrong, my knowledge on design pattern is very low.

[image]

**Controlller**

BookController - Class with rest api to pass data to frontend

**Model**

Book - Parent class with variables and relevant methods
Novel - Child class with variables and relevant methods
Poems - Child class with variables and relevant methods
MyBookManager - BookManager interface implemented class which includes crud operations with mongoDB

**View**

BookManager - Interface related to MyBookManager 
Console - Class which takes the input from users from the the console and calls methods in MyBookManager  to save them to DB

**Repository**

BookRepository - Interface which extends MongoRepository

**Other classes**

BookStoreApplication - Class which includes the main method
ErrorHandle - Class which includes methods for validations

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Package names should always be lowercase. Why is there a an interface BookManager and why is the implmenetation in the model package?

Comment: Interface BookManager contains the crud methods and those methods are overridden in MyBookManager class.   MyBookManager class is responsible for crud operations with DB, so I thought it should be in Model

Comment: Yes but then you also have to put the interface there. But you can completly remove the interface if there is only one implemention